# postgresql with parameter in query

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Recently i created a stored procedure in postgresql to create tables with jdbc in java, i pass the table name like a parameter in a function and it seems go well, but it is possible to pass the table name in the query create table? I mean:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_tables(t_name character varying)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (tname_test varchar(100));
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (tname_nos int);
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I (tname_pro int);',
   t_name || 'cabecera', t_name || 'contenido', t_name || 'procesado');
END
$function$;
```

something like that, im going to create a lots of tables with the same attributtes so i want to differenciate each other with the table name to go fist in my name atributtes.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you need correctly, you can use [quote_ident](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

Here is a code example :

```
DO $$
DECLARE table_name text:= 'demo';
DECLARE column_name text:= 'column_';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE ' || quote_ident(table_name || '_test')||' (' ||quote_ident(column_name||'a')|| ' integer,' ||quote_ident(column_name||'b')|| ' integer)';
END $$;
SELECT * FROM demo_test;
```